# Cannot connect to Azure in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, firewall

Really frustrated at this stage :/

I need to connect on a remote server in Microsoft SQL Server Studio. However this is error is showing:
[image: Connection Popup]
[image: Error Popup]

I did/tried the following solutions:

1. Turning off the Firewall.
2. Allowing Remote Connections for the SQL Database.
3. Enabling TCP/IP within the SQL Configuration.
4. Enabling SQL Server Browser in SQL Configuration.
5. Allowed 1433 TCP on Inbound Firewall.
6. Tried the following format in the server name field:  **MyServerName,1433\InstanceName**
7. Restarting SQL Server in services.msc
8. Added firewall rule in azure using public ip address

I tried all of these and none work. Do you guys have any other possible solutions?

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio v18.5.1.

Hoping to hear from you soon.

Comment: That looks like a Azure SQL Database Server Name, rather than a server hosting SQL Server in Azure. If it is a VM, have you enabled connectionfs from your IP to the host's in  Network Security Group in the Azure Portal? If it is a Azure SQL Database, you need to add your IP in the Firewalls and virtual networks section of the Azure portal.

Comment: Hi Larnu! I actually all of this installation to my older laptop and I don't even need to do all the things I did above. I just logged in and i successfully accessed it. I don't know if what you said is necessary :/

Comment: So are you saying you solved the problem?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying is that I am trying to setup this Server on another laptop. I don't know why it seems complicated on this machine, but on my other laptop, I didn't do any of the things I did above.

Comment: Installing SQL Server on a laptop would never result in an Azure SQL Database Server Name. We're missing information here. Are you installing SQL Server locally or in the cloud? If locally, why are you using an Azure SQL Database Server Name? If in the Cloud, what does the laptop with a different instance have to do with the the one in the cloud?

Comment: I did not install the server in my laptop. I am trying to connect on a remote server. Now on the other laptop, I just filled up the credentials like server name, username, and password and I was able to connect easily and successfully. 

However, on this laptop that I am talking about, the error I screenshot is showing. I did all of the possible solutions I mentioned above but none worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215658/discussion-between-earl-fojas-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was on my internet service provider. When I'm using 5G WiFi it does not continue and show the error. But when I'm using 2.4G it's working properly.